# Surefire wont trigger the integration tests

Tags: maven, testing, integration-testing, spring-test, maven-surefire-plugin

I am facing this issue in my Spring MVC project:

I have two types of tests. Unit and Integration. Both separated by package in test/java, respectively by test/java/unit and test/java/integration. I am using maven-surefire plugin to trigger tests.

I have two profiles, `unit` and `integration` defined in pom.xml

```
<profile>
    <id>unit</id>            
    <properties>
        <include.tests>**/unit/**/*.java</include.tests>
    </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>integration</id>            
    <properties>
        <include.tests>**/integration/**/*.java</include.tests>
        ... other properties for configuring integration platform (DB, ...) omitted for simplicity
    </properties>
</profile>
```

And surefire plugin is configured like this

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>${include.tests}</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I run `mvn surefire:test -Punit`, all unit tests are triggered, which is what I want (I´ve checked the amount of tests passed is same as amount of tests passed when I trigger them by unit folder for example from IDEA).

But when I try to run `mvn surefire:test -Pintegration`, the task will run and "succeed", but the number of tests peformed is 0. But when I run these tests from IDEA for example with `Integration` profile active, I see there is X tests which will run successfully.

Basic integration tests uses `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` for running test (plus some config xmls to configure other properties).

Unit tests are JUnit 5 based using Mockito.

Comment: First integration tests should be handled by maven-failsafe-plugin and follow naming conventions like `*IT.java` much better. Furthermore unit tests should follow naming conventions as well like `*Test.java` and should be in the same packages of the units they are testing. Apart from that if you are using JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) then the usage of `@RunWith` does not make sense because that is related to JUnit 4.X or you are using junit-jupiter-vintage-engine instead (or it must be configured which I can't see here). Running of IT's should be done via `mvn verify` without a profile!

Comment: @khmarbaise I am aware that conventions that are currently set are not the best I can manage but thats the situation I cant easily change now. The RunWith is for integration tests only (Which I can not change due to low spring-test version, otherwise I would´ve changed that). The JUnit 5 unit tests are "separated" from this and can be separated. There are other "old" tests I can not delete but I do not want to run them.Thats the reason. So the basic thing is to be able to run tests in /unit and /integration separately somehow.Basically automatize what I am doing in IDEA (Run tests by folder)

Comment: @khmarbaise Ad2 : running mvn verify will not trigger a single test. Build end successfuly but number of tests ran is 0 (so as running surefire with integration profile)

Comment: First which Spring boot version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise Sadly It is not a Spring Boot app. But its Spring MVC on version 4.3.6 (core) (with no chance to migrate to Boot now, the mail goal to make this work)

Comment: Than first do not try to go with JUnit JUpiter keep JUnit 4 furthermore I strongly recommend to change those things profile stuff and follow conventions in Maven it's easier (verify will not run tests because you have not configured maven-failsafe-plugin yet). Migration path is not by separating the tests... use vintage engine to run JUnit 4 tests on JUnit 5 and then remove the JUnit 4 specifics but I wouldn't do that in such case.

Comment: @khmarbaise Well, as I said I get its not a cool situation but the goal I need to do right now to make this work without any further upgrades or changes. I do not really get why tests working like a charm when I run it from IDEA but not when I run. Even `mvn package -Dtest=integration.* -DfailIfNoTests=false -DfailIfNoSpecifiedTests=false -am` with that failsafe wont trigger any tests.

Comment: If you state that: `work without any further upgrades or changes.` .. I would say that will not work apart from making sense.

Comment: @khmarbaise Well the some roadmap contains these upgrades you suggested but for now I need to run these tests separately. So there is no change to make this work in this state?

Comment: You have made already changes by using JUnit 5 ... which in consequence need other changes etc. ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Well yes, but using JUnit 5 in unit tests was pretty easy with no need to other updates. But When I tried to change that JUnit4Runner to SpringExtension, I could not cause I would need to update spring-test up to (at least) one major version with all Spring MVC stack which will cause a lot of problems (and which I would like to upgrade to Boot instead in future). And thats not a thing to perform in one day in such a big app like this. So I am looking for solution to my problem which will not cause a lot of refactors.